# Extra terrestrial origin of Indians

Tags: mahabharata, mantras

Kunti called upon Indra, Vayu, Yama,to beget a child using Durvasa's Mantra.

What was the mantra, and have any other mantras been used in a similar way since the times of Mahabharat?

By virtue of this mantra the progeny of Bharat the Indians of such ancient origins won wars and a majority ruled kingdoms also.

Can a part of Bharat then lay claim  to have an extra terrestrial (celestial) origin?

Comment: The mantra was given in secret to Kuntī by Durvāsā. It's a really special mantra, and isn't disclosed by Vyāsa. By the way many Rājās and Ṛṣis had special births, Pāṇḍavas are just few of the many.

Comment: Even meditation mantras as supposed to be secret. The secrecy is more to whom or in what manner it is given rather than the source or content itself... right?

Comment: *Generally*, mantras that are given in upadeśa/dīkṣā by an ācārya/guru to a śiṣya are secret, and aren't to be disclosed to others randomly. When such a mantra (that's meant to be kept secret with oneself) is disclosed to anyone randomly by oneself, one may incur pāpa.